# jquery datatable with serverside processing generate and catch validation and other errors

Tags: php, ajax, datatable, header

I am using jquery datatable with serverside processing. How to generate error on php serverside and then catch and display to user.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the `error` parameter in server side returned data, Datatable should show the message.
reference https://datatables.net/manual/server-side